# Kubernetes Ingree IP is not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

In K8s cluster with 1 Master and 3 nodes on AWS

1. Ingress services are able to pull IP (and IP is one of Nodes Public IP). But not reachable from outside.
2. Both ingress services have same IP.

Can any please clarify, How different services are distingvished with same IP.

```
     root@ravi:/home/# kubectl get ing --all-namespaces
     NAMESPACE   NAME            HOSTS             ADDRESS  PORTS     AGE
     2048-game   nginx-ingress   2048.exam.com    1.2.3.4   80        1h
      default    echomap         bar.baz.com      1.2.3.4   80        2h
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ingress services are able to pull IP (and IP is one of Nodes Public IP). But not reachable from outside.

That can be a firewall problem. Check Security Group of your nodes, maybe it is denied to connect to Ingress port from outside.

> Both ingress services have same IP.

[Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) is an object which contain an instruction for your Ingress Controller how to process request addressed to different hosts. All requests for any host actually going to the Ingress Controller, which processing it based on "Host" header. Actually, it working like [Name-Based virtual hosting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

That's why all your Ingresses have same IP and it is an IP and port of your Ingress Controller.